# No static method canDrawOverlays

Tags: android

I've noticed someone who is using my app reported a crash which logged by the Google Developer Console:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method canDrawOverlays(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class Landroid/provider/Settings; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.provider.Settings' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
    at com.pack.MainActivity.checkDrawOverlayPermission(MainActivity.java:311)
    at com.pack.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:127)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

The `canDrawOverlays` is an API 23+ method and I Use it like that:

```
 /** code to post/handler request for permission */
    public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 100; /*(see edit II)*/

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            /** if not construct intent to request permission */
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            /** request permission via start activity for result */
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

And I have this in my MainActivity:

```
checkDrawOverlayPermission();
```

The device which crashed using Android 5.1

HOw I can make sure my app will work on ANdroid 5.1? (API 22 and below) who don't have this method which available from API 23 and up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the current API of the device which runs your code. If it >= 23, you can use the code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
     // if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
     //
} else {
     // another similar method that supports device have API < 23 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

       if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        /** request permission via start activity for result */ 
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } 

    } else {
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For all methods that appeared in newer SDK versions you should use the following pattern:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  // code for Marshmallow (SDK 23) and newer versions
} else {
  // fallback for older versions
}
```