# Settings.canDrawOverlays permission grant issue

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Can I use `Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)` method for the application which having `minSdkVersion= 16`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No static method canDrawOverlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911130/no-static-method-candrawoverlays)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. API 23+ only I'm afraid.